# Misra C error in Macro definition

Tags: c, macros, misra

This piece of code reports three misra c errors:

1. Inappropriate macro expansion
2. Function-like macro definition
3. Macro parameter with no parentheses

The original code is:

```
#define Wait(a, b)                         \
if (READ(b+0x1U))                          \
{                                          \
    while ((a & Write(b)))                 \
    {                                      \
        /* Do nothing - Busy wait */       \
    }                                      \
}

Here READ(b) is a macro and Write(b) is a function with no Misra C error.
```

I have trying changing it to remove errors

```
#define Wait(a, b)                                                 \
if ((uint32_t)0U != READ((b)+0x1U))                                \
{                                                                  \
    while ((uint32_t)0U != ((uint32_t)(a) & Write((uint32_t)(b)))) \
    {                                                              \
        /* Do nothing - Busy wait */                               \
    }                                                              \
}
```

But i am still getting the first two errors. What needs to be done to remove these Misra C errors.

Comment: Which version of MISRA are you using?  What tool are you using to check it?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I am using Klocwrok 10.0. Not sure about MISRA version. These errors are reference 19.4, 19.7 and 19.10 respectively.

Comment: That would be MISRA-C:2004.

Answer (score 6):

> 1.Inappropriate macro expansion

This is because you haven't encapsulated your macro properly. To fix this, you must change the code to:

```
#define Wait(a, b)                         \
                                           \
do {                                       \
  if (READ(b+0x1U))                        \
  {                                        \
    while ((a & Write(b)))                 \
    {                                      \
        /* Do nothing - Busy wait */       \
    }                                      \
  }                                        \
} while (0);
```

(But of course, this is pointless exercise if the rest of your code follows MISRA-C and always use `{}` after every `if`, `for` or `while` statement.)

---

> 2.Function-like macro definition

You are using a function-like macro. This isn't allowed by MISRA-C. Rewrite the macro as a function.

However, rule 19.7 is advisory, so you could in theory ignore it without raising a deviation. But there is no reason to do so in this case. There exists no reason why this need to be a macro and not a function.

---

> 3.Macro parameter with no parentheses

As you guessed, this has to do with every macro parameter being a potential sub-expression. Suppose someone calls your macro as `Wait(x+y, z)`. Your code will then crash and burn upon encountering the while loop, because the macro will expand into `while(x+y & Write(b))`, which is the same thing as `while(x + (y & Write(b)) )`.

To solve this, surround every instance of `a` and `b` with parenthesis, as in your second example.

---

> This piece of code reports three misra c errors:

You should report a bug to Klockwork, their tool is not working correctly. It should also have detected the following:

- `if (READ(b+0x1U))` violates rules 13.2. MISRA compliant code would be

  ```
  if (READ(b+0x1U) != 0u)
  ```
- `while ((a & Write(b)))` violates rule 13.2. MISRA compliant code would be

  ```
  while ( (a & Write(b)) != 0u )
  ```

---

Non-MISRA related concerns:

- `(uint32_t)0U` should preferably be written as `0UL` or `0ul`, which are more readable forms.
- Frankly, this code was bad to begin with. Trying to make it MISRA-compliant as it stands, will turn it into a completely unreadable mess. Rewrite it from scratch instead:

  ```
  void Wait (uint32_t a, uint32 b)
  {
    if( READ(b + 0x1u) != 0u )           /* comment here, explaining the code */
    {
      while ( (a & Write(b)) != 0u )     /* comment here, explaining the code */
      {
        ;                                /* Do nothing - busy wait */
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

There's a list of things macros are allowed to expand to, and an if block isn't one of them.  I believe this is because it can cause confusion about the attachment of else clauses.  [More about that here.](http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html)  You can use this construct:

```
#define MACRO(X)    \
do {                \
    body here       \
} while (0)
```

You should use a function instead of a function-like macro whenever you can.  Without knowing what READ expands to I can't say if that's possible in this case.  That would be the only way to get rid of the warning about that.

The third one you already figured out; you have to put parentheses around `a` and `b` in the body.  The idea here is that if you have code like `x*2` in the macro and someone passes `3+1` as x, without the parenthesis you'd get `3+1*2`, which is 5, instead of `(3+1)*2`, which is the 8 which was almost certainly intended.

The only other thing I would have to say about your code is are you sure you want `&` there and not `&&`?

Comment: Yes, & only is required. Samuel I was able to solve first by using braces {} before if and at the end i.e. #define Wait(a,b) \ { if... }. Is this correct way to solve it?

Comment: @RogMatthews, the problem with doing it that way is if you call it like `if (x) Wait(a, b); else foo();` you will get a syntax error because it expands to `if (x) { ... }; else ...` and that semicolon can't be there.  Using `do { ... } while (0)` resolves this because a semicolon is required after the while portion.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard If you write MISRA compatible code, that's a non-issue, since MISRA would have enforced you to write `if (x) { Wait(a, b); }` when calling the macro. Only people who insist on skipping braces after statements get these kind of obscure bugs.

Comment: @Lundin Certainly, but I think it's worth the small effort to write it so that it will work correctly even if the person reusing your code does something MISRA doesn't approve of.